# SQL 2012 my MAX in my select is not displaying the max value

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Sorry for formatting issues! I don't know it works on this site :(

I'm trying to return just the highest Total in my Sale table for the month of January, but it returns every sale in that month not just the highest.

```
select
  EMP.FirstName,
  EMP.LastName,
  EMP.Email,
  SAL.SaleNumber,
  SAL.SaleDate,
  max(SAL.Total) Total
from 
  Employee EMP
  INNER JOIN Sale SAL
    ON EMP.EmployeeNumber = SAL.EmployeeNumber

--Assuming the month is January of 2015, because there were no sales for this month (March).
where
  SAL.SaleDate between '20150101 00:00:00.000' and '20150131 23:59:59.997'

group by
  EMP.FirstName,
  EMP.LastName,
  EMP.Email,
  SAL.SaleNumber,
  SAL.SaleDate,
  SAL.Total
```

Comment: You've tagged multiple databases.  I assume you're using `SQL Server 2012` and not `mysql`?

Comment: Also why are you grouping by SAL.Total?

Comment: Learn how group by works

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to get each employee's maximum sale for a given time frame?  If so, one option would be to use a ranking function such as `row_number`:

```
with cte as (
select
  EMP.FirstName,
  EMP.LastName,
  EMP.Email,
  SAL.SaleNumber,
  SAL.SaleDate,
  SAL.Total,
  row_number() over (partition by EMP.EmployeeNumber 
                     order by SAL.Total DESC) rn
from 
  Employee EMP
  INNER JOIN Sale SAL
    ON EMP.EmployeeNumber = SAL.EmployeeNumber
where
  SAL.SaleDate >= '20150101 00:00:00.000' and 
  SAL.SaleDate < '20150201 00:00:00.000'
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Also please note, I'd suggest using `>=` and `<` for this type of date filtering.

Comment: sgeddes: I executed your code and it gave the same answer as mine, returns every total not just the maximum total. And yes I'm using SQL Server 2012 sorry.

Comment: @BrendanX -- this would return each employee with their highest sale.  If you only want to return a single result, remove `partition by EMP.EmployeeNumber`.  Hard to completely understand without sample data and expected results.

Comment: Thanks sgeddes, I'm new to this site and wasn't sure about posting results, but I removed partition by EMP.EmployeeNumber and it displays just the top result, thank you very much!

Comment: Another quick question, is there something else I can use instead of "select *", I'd rather not use a * ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume looking for the top sale. Your query gets the top sale for each salenumber which ends up being each and every sale.

```
select top 1
  EMP.FirstName,
  EMP.LastName,
  EMP.Email,
  SAL.SaleNumber,
  SAL.SaleDate,
  SAL.Total
from 
  Employee EMP
  INNER JOIN Sale SAL
    ON EMP.EmployeeNumber = SAL.EmployeeNumber

Order by sal.total desc
```

Comment: This might be what the OP is looking for -- just use `top 1` instead of `limit` since this is for `SQL Server`.